# specific category discount

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, cart-rule

I have been trying to create a Promotions>Shopping Cart Price Rule, of 10% discount for Category A (id=8).  So when 2 products are added to the cart, discount only applies to the product belonging to category id=8.

Rule Information:
Rule Name: 10PercentOff
Parameters set are:
Status: Active
Customer Groups:
- NOT LOGGED IN
- General
- Wholesale
- Retailer
Coupon: Specific Coupon
Uses per Customer: 1

- First attempt using conditions Only.
  **Conditions:**
  If **ANY** of these conditions are **TRUE**:
  "+" Product Attribute Combination > If an item is **FOUND** in the cart with **ANY** of these conditions **true**:
  Product Attribute>Category Category  is  8.
  When I add a product from category 8 and also add another product from another category, *the cart discounts both products*.
- Second attempt using Action Only.
  **Actions:**
  If **ALL** of these conditions are **TRUE**:
  "+" Product Attribute>Category Category is 8.
  When I add a product from category 8 and also add another product from another category, *the cart produces the message* **Coupon code "10PercentOff" is not valid**.
  [image]
  I should also add this, when both "Conditions" and "Actions" are untouched (no set rules), the discount gets applied. It gets applied to the entire cart.  As seen in the picture below:
  [image: With no rules in Condition or Actions]
  How can this be achieved?  How should rules be created for this scenario?

Comment: Your second attempt looks like it should work to me in rule information have you got it customer groups set up for the discount?

Comment: Both your rules are working, the first Any condition, matches a product and discounts the cart and in the second attempt, your rule/action requires all products to be in category 8, when you apply the coupon to a cart with products in another category the coupon is invalid.

Comment: @Bobadevv Sorry for that, I just updated the question.  Customer groups are set as, Customer Groups: NOT LOGGED IN, General, Wholesale and  Retailer.  With **Actions** set as described above, and no rules are set in **Conditions**,  I get `Coupon code "10PercentOff" is not valid`! With have 2 products in cart, one belonging to ID=8 and another to another category group.

Comment: Do you have a url for your site

Comment: @paj I am sorry, I am a little confused with your comment. I tried applying the rules described in my attempts in both Conditions and Action, Conditions Only and Actions Only.

Comment: @Bobadevv sorry it's local server.

Comment: Your second attempt should work fine. Are you sure to insert the correct coupon code?

Comment: @WaPoNe As I mentioned in the questions, when the above rule is set ONLY in Actions tab, I get the "Coupon code "10PercentOff" is not valid" message.